# How can I change existing values to a new category in the same column?

Tags: r

Based on the table below, how would I be able to put "wedding" and "renewable_energy" which both occur less frequently, into the "other" category?

[image]

Comment: Using ifelse: `loans$reason <- ifelse(loans$reason %in% c("wedding", "renewable_energy"), "other", loans$reason)`

Comment: That changed the values to numbers for some reason, but it kept other

Comment: Provide example data, and expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loans$reason <- factor(ifelse(as.character(loans$reason) %in% c("wedding", "renewable_energy"), "other", loans$reason))
```

Your reason column is probably of type factor, hence it changed to numbers, so you need to convert to character first. And optionally, after that to factor again.

Comment: That still replaces the variables with numbers for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: Then please add sample data and expected output as @zx8754 mentioned so we can look into it.